# std::length_error after resizing a vector to more than 2^31

Tags: c++

std::length_error after resizing a vector more than 2^31 . Simple error when:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<bool> arr;
    arr.resize(2147483650,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Error is :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector<bool>::_M_fill_insert
```

if I go for anything below 2^31 I'm fine. I need a bool vector longer than 2^31 and now I have enough RAM for it. How do I solve this? (Maybe raise std::length_error limit somehow?)

P.S. this is probably a duplicate Q but I can't find a solution anywhere... (when I search this on google I only find string errors). Also, maybe I'm imagining things but I'm pretty sure I managed to resize this and not get an error a week ago. I don't know.

Comment: Are you compiling as a 32-bit program? Try compiling as a 64-bit program instead.

Comment: What is [`max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size) telling you the max size is?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude from the program in your link I got ```Maximum size of a 'vector' is 2147483647``` . How do I change it? also, is there a way to change array max size?

Comment: You can't change the max size yourself. And why do you need that many elements in a vector? What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698250/fast-algorithm-to-factorize-all-numbers-up-to-a-given-number

The 'P.S.' of my question. still, do I need to reinstall g++ (or something similar...) to get it working?

Comment: How many elements do you intend to allocate?

Comment: @Lainad what system are you using and what compiler (version)? For gcc, try compiling with `-m64`.

Comment: Hey everyone,

just looked on the MINGW installer and I only got a gcc32. My system is 64 bit though.  (also `-m64` gives `cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in`). How do I install the 64 bit one? can't see in the installer.

Comment: Related: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942923/509868) with answer

Comment: @anatolyg alright then! that settles it I guess. If I install and everything goes smoothly I will likely delete the question.

Comment: When my data exceeds the capacity of being stored in-memory, I use a database solution as the data backing store.  (The "go to" I use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), but there are other [embedded database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) options that you may find more suitable to your needs.)

Answer (score 0):

As written in comments, in 32-bit systems 2<sup>31</sup> is a kind of hard limit, which you can never exceed.

One workaround for that is to use `uint8_t` (or any other unsigned integer type) instead of `bool` for elements of the vector. This will increase your limit to 2<sup>34</sup> bits, but will require some uncomfortable changes in code. Standard `vector<bool>` implementation does all the required bit-fiddling, but it cannot exceed 2<sup>31</sup> elements because indices/iterators cannot be implemented with 32-bit integers.

But the ultimate solution is to compile as 64-bit.

Comment: Installed gcc64. Everything goes smoothly (also, using bitsets now :) ). Thx